# Extract property and value in a functional way in JavaScript

Tags: javascript, arrays, arrow-functions

Consider we have an array containing all the properties of an object that we are interested to have their values extracted from an array of objects. Each in a form of an object.

```
var keys = ['name', 'age'];
```

Let say we have an array of students. A student object looks like:

```
var student = {name:"Sarah", age:"20", address:"123 Main St."};
```

we have an array of students.

Using the code below its possible to extract properties and values that we are interested from each student. The properties that we are interested in are our keys mentioned above.

```
function pluck(keys) {
   return function(students) {
        return students.map(i => {
            var ex = {};
            for (var k = 0; k < keys.length; k++) {
                if (i.hasOwnProperty(keys[k])) {
                    ex[keys[k]] = i[keys[k]]; 
                }
            }
            return ex;
        });
    };
}
```

I think there is a better and simpler way of doing this especially the for loop part using arrow functions but cannot figure this out. Could anyone shed some light on this.

Comment: Where you have 'items', I think you mean 'students' (or vice-versa). Actual answer coming separately.

Comment: I guess my first question is what is `items`. How it looks like. I assume `student` is your expected output?

Comment: Thanks @SMcCrohan. I made the correction.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do like this. It's pretty functional;

```js
var keys = ["name","age"],
students = [{name:"Sarah", age:"20", address:"123 Main St."},
            {name:"Janet", age:"21", address:"123 Main St."},
            {name:"Peter", age:"22", address:"123 Main St."},
            {name:"Jesse", age:"19", address:"123 Main St."},
            {name:"Marla", age:"20", address:"123 Main St."}
           ],
  result = students.reduce((p,c) => p.concat(keys.reduce((o,k) => Object.assign(o,{[k]: c[k]}),{})),[]);
console.log(result);
```

Answer (score 1):

Easy answer is use the common pattern for extracting properties from a single object using `reduce` and apply to an array of objects using `map`

```js
function selectFromArray(array, keys) {
  return array.map(function(item) {
    return keys.reduce(function(o, k) {
      o[k] = item[k];
      return o;
    }, {});
  });
}

var keys = ['age', 'name'];
var students = [{age: 5,name: 'joe',sex: 'm'}, {age: 6,name: 'sue',sex: 'f'}];
var subset = selectFromArray(students, keys);
alert(JSON.stringify(subset));
```